# Работа с частью вектора как с вектором

Tags: c++

Есть стандартный вектор, допустим типа `std::vector<int>`. Есть функция `void plusOne(std::vector<int>::iterator it1, std::vector<int>::iterator it2)`, прибавляющая всем элементам между первым (на который указывает it1) и последним (на который указывает it2) единицу. Можно написать перегруженную функция `void plusOne(std::vector<int>)`, которая будет делать то же самое с целым вектором.

Есть ли способ заставить второй вариант функции работать с частью вектора (кроме очевидного и неэффективного: создать временный вектор, скопировать туда нужные значения, обработать, скопировать новые значения в старое место)?

Comment: Вы и в первом случае теряете обобщенность - указывая, что это не просто итераторы, а итераторы вектора (зачем?), а уж во втором и подавно. Но пусть его... Как вы вообще представляете себе передачу одним аргументом - вектором (кстати, еще и с передачей по значению... описка?) - **его части**? Вот у вас вектор `a` - как вы собираетесь передать в функцию его первую половину?

Comment: все можно, если сделать некий класс с названием `vector_view` (даже [есть пример реализации](https://gist.github.com/r-lyeh/5475c8ddde9f07f6f7aa)) и его использовать в объявлении функции `plusOne`.

Comment: @KoVadim Можно, `string_view` вообще в стандарте... но это же резкое снижение обобщенности, с одной стороны, да и ведь все равно нужно будет создавать объект, при инициализации которого указывать начало и конец. И зачем эти телодвижения, если **уже** имеется функция с двумя итераторами? (в вопросе это говорится недвусмысленно)

Comment: а разве нельзя просто передать итераторы не с начала до конца, а с определённого места?

Comment: Если можно, может использовать связанный список а не вектор в таком случае?

Answer (score 1):

Концепция итераторов для этого и предназначена. Если для вас это не удобно, есть [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) ([примеры](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html#tutorial-quick-start)), `view::slice` позволяет взять произвольную часть диапазона как единую структуру.

Пример:

```
using namespace ranges;
auto input_range =  view::ints(1) | view::transform([](int i){return i*i;});

auto output_range = input_range| view::take(10);

int sum = accumulate(output_range, 0);
```

Создает диапазон от 1 до бесконечности, лениво возводит элементы в квадрат и берёт первые десять элементов от результата (т.е. как раз кусок диапазона как единую структуру).

Edit: Если вам нужно передать диапазон в функцию, приходится передавать его как шаблон. Со статическими проверками есть проблема, пока что это выглядит примерно так:

```
template<class Rng,
    CONCEPT_REQUIRES_(Range<Rng>())>
void my_algorithm(Rng && rng)
{
    return my_algorithm(ranges::begin(rng), ranges::end(rng));
}
```